# fileinfo.CreationTime stays the same after new file is created

Tags: c#, .net

I have a logging class.  It created a new log.txt file if one isn't present and writes messsages to that file.  I also have a method that runs to check the file size and when the file was created against local settings.  If the difference between the log.txt's creation time and the current time exceeds the local settings MaxLogHours value, then it is archived to a local archive folder and deleted.  The new log.txt file is created by the above process the next time a log message is sent to the class.

This works great, except when I look at the FileInfo.CreationTime for my log.txt file, it is always the same - 7/17/2012 12:05/18 PM - no matter what I do.  I've manually deleted the file, the program deletes it, always the same.  What is going on here?  I also timestamp the old ones, but still nothing works.  Does Windows think that the file is the same one because it has the same filename?  I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

archive method

```
    public static void ArchiveLog(Settings s)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\log.txt");
        string archiveDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\archive";
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - fi.CreationTime;

        if ((s.MaxLogKB != 0 && fi.Length >= s.MaxLogKB * 1000) || 
            (s.MaxLogHours != 0 && ts.TotalHours >= s.MaxLogHours))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(archiveDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDir);
            }
            string archiveFile = archiveDir + "\\log" + string.Format("{0:MMddyyhhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".txt";

            File.Copy(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\log.txt", archiveFile);
            File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\log.txt");
        }
    }
```

Writing/Creating the log:

```
public static void MsgLog(string Msg, bool IsStandardMsg = true)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\log.txt", true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Msg at " + DateTime.Now + " - " + Msg);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(Msg);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did You wait some minutes after You created the file initially and then deleted it and then recreated it ?

Answer (score 1):

This may happened , so it's writen in [FileSystemInfo.CreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx)

> This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native
>   functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the
>   operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using FileInfo.CreationTime without first checking if the file still exists. Run this POC - it will always generate "After delete CreationTime: 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM" - because file does not exists anymore and you did not touch FileInfo.CreationTime prior to delete. However if you uncomment the line:

```
//Console.WriteLine("Before delete CreationTime: {0}", fi.CreationTime);
```

in the code below strangely both calls will return correct and updated value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication17088573
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {


                string fname = "testlog.txt";

                using (var fl = File.Create(fname))
                {
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fl))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Current datetime is {0}", DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }
                var fi = new FileInfo(fname);
                //Console.WriteLine("Before delete CreationTime: {0}", fi.CreationTime);
                File.Delete(fname);
                Console.WriteLine("After delete CreationTime: {0}", fi.CreationTime);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);


            }

        }
    }
}
```